# How to Show Total Post Views of User in WordPress community theme?

Tags: wordpress, post-meta

So, here I am using Boombox Theme for my community website and I wanna show "Total post reads/views" from a user, for example an A user has 10 post and has various views each post, I need the total view from all of A's post. is it possible to do it in wordpress platform? since what i found in my database tables, i couldn't find any related field i could "play" for.

I've tried to modify an update_post_meta function, tried to add another condition on the function.php file, but it doesn't work.

here's the function:

```
function boombox_update_post_total_view( $scale, $post_id ) {
    if( absint( $scale ) > 0 ) {
        $total = intval( boombox_get_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_views' ) );
        $total += $scale;

        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_views', $total);

    }
}

add_action( 'boombox/view_total_updated', 'boombox_update_post_total_view', 10, 2 );
```

and here's the database table structure:
[database table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoTnC.png)

thank you.
NB: I don't even sure that I edited the correct file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work with any theme.

**Step 1:**
Add this codes from the following block in your themes **function.php** file.

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
// Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

**Step 2:** Add this line of code to **single.php** file. Please note that it should be inside the loop, you can add it right after `the_content()`:

```
setPostViews(get_the_ID());
```

For example, it should be:

```
the_content(); setPostViews(get_the_ID());
```

**Step 3:** Add this line of code where you want to show the total of post's view:

```
echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
```

Source: https://www.themexpert.com/blog/track-display-post-views-in-wordpress

Comment: okaaay, I don't know is it work the way I wanted or not, but I already found what I want, I appreciate your answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

here's the code I used now :)

```
 <?php
                                            $profile_id = bp_get_member_user_id();
                                            $balance    = mycred_get_users_balance( $profile_id );
                                            $author_id = ''; // do stuff to get user ID
                                            $author_posts = get_posts( array(
                                                'author' => $profile_id
                                            ) );

                                            $counter = 0; // needed to collect the total sum of views

                                            foreach ( $author_posts as $post )
                                            {
                                                $views = absint( boombox_get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'total_views', true ) );
                                                $counter += $views;
                                            }
                                        ?>
```